# Replacing sprites idea

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Ok so I am very bad at sprites and I just don't get how to use sprites with blitted images. So I was wondering, if I make the image and just make a rectangle around that object that follows that image around, would that be a good replacement for sprites, the rectangle would be the one that's colliding for instances... Or should I try learning sprites. If I should is there any tutorial that could help me with using blitted images to make sprite characters that use python 3.4?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, most uses for sprites can work with rectangular collision boxes. Only if you had an instance where a ball needed to be collided with then you would have to use an actual sprite. In the long run, I would recommend learning sprites, but if you need help with sprites, the pygame documentation has loads of information!

Comment: K thanks, I guess it's time to try relearning sprites... yay.